# R CMD INSTALL is stuck on a function that works... how can I debug this further?

Tags: r, installation

*note:* much of the information in the problem statement is irrelevant, and the problem has been resolved with no apparent reason through the debugging steps that are listed in the **resolution** section

*I apologize for asking a question about an error that I can not reproduce.*

**Problem**

I have a test function 'foo.R' in my package 'PKG'; foo.R consists of:

```
foo <- function (filename, n) {
  text <- scan(file = filename, what = "character")
  if (n==1) text <- gsub("\\#GGG", '\\#', text)
  if (n>1)  text <- gsub("\\#GGG", '', text)
  writeLines(text, con = 'newfn.R')
}
```

The intent of foo is to either uncomment lines by replacing "#GGG" with "" when n>1 or to leave the line commented if n == 1

The minimal code required to produce this error is:

```
foo <- function (string) {
    gsub("\\#GGG", '', string)
}
```

However, when I run `R CMD INSTALL PKG` I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  /tmp/RtmpLbFQF0/R.INSTALL2edd9a07/PKG/R/foo.R:3:1: unexpected '}'
2:   gsub("\\#GGG", '\\#', string)
3: }
   ^
```

**UPDATES**

1. Based on the answers, '\#' is not the culprit.
2. I have found that the problem is during install (not build), and I have changed the question to reflect this. I have also fixed the curly braces from my test case.
3. Also, I have found that not only does the function work, e.g. when loaded with source(),

   - When I make a new project (e.g. 'newproject') and move the function there, it installs without error, i.e. this works:

     1. move foo.R to newproject/R/foo.R
     2. make a newproject/DESCRIPTION
     3. R CMD build newproject
     4. R CMD INSTALL newproject
   - This gives the error above:

     1. R CMD build PKG
     2. R CMD INSTALL PKG
4. In response to the request for the error output log, the output from `R CMD check PKG` is the same as the error from the `R CMD INSTALL PKG`,

> - installing *source* package ‘PKG’ ...
>     ** R Error in parse(outFile) :    /home/user/PKG/R/foo.R:24:0:
>     unexpected end of input 22:
>     writeLines(model.text, con = outfile)
>     23: }    ^ ERROR: unable to collate
>     files for package ‘PKG’
> - removing ‘/home/user/PKG.Rcheck/PKG’

**Resolution**

The resolution of the error is inexplicable, but I reproduced the same seemingly magical method on two functions with the same error.

1. `mv /PKG/R/foo.R PKG/foo.R`
2. Visit new `PKG/R/foo.R` in emacs
3. for (i in misc bits of function

   1. cut-and-paste i
   2. `R CMD check PKG`
   3. if `PKG` can install
   4. return to `1`
   5. else remove bits and return to `3`
4. `diff PKG/foo.R PKG/R/foo.R`
5. if no difference except that function now works

   1. update question on SO
   2. consider previous error a fluke
   3. continue as if nothing happened

### UPDATE 2: culprit found!

The problem was an errant 'e' stuck to the left of the comment symbols ## coming before a function

Comment: You have not provided enough information to provide an answer - it's probably another function in the same file that's causing the problem.

Comment: If by your actual package you mean one containing only the function `foo()` defined at the top of the page, then I can *not* reproduce your problem. Such a package checks and installs fine under R2.12.1 RC on Linux.

Comment: It still looks like there's a missing curly bracket or similar somewhere. Could you zip up your package directory and get it to us? Seems nobody can reproduce this.

Comment: @Spacedman; I think that was just the error he pasted when testing. If you try the real `foo.R` there is no problem. I'm reading this as though @David didn't edit his Q to remove or update the message. If that **is** still the error he is getting, then time to get a better editor to help @David spot syntax errors, as your comment above would seem to hit the nail on the head. If that *is* the error, what more help is required to debug? There is a syntax error (shown) in the file named. Whenever I've got stuck like this, it is usually my own error not rechecking things I think I checked were OK!

Comment: My two cents: have you checked that when you change `"\\#GGG"` to `"GGG"` it will work? This way you will know if `#` makes an error.

Comment: I think now we either need: the full zip archive source of the failing package, or at least a full transcript of the output from R when it fails, not just 'i get this error message'. Full disclosure! Its a good thing!

Comment: @Spacedman now that the error has stopped, it wouldn't be worthwhile for me to send it. I also believe in full disclosure, especially toward the goal of producing research that is reproducible, I am not comfortable providing incomplete code in this forum, although I would consider sharing if a direct request were made to me via email.

Comment: It might be an unreproducible error, but the question is asked clearly, so no reason to downvote. I vote to close, as the problem apparently doesn't exist. But also that is decently added to the question.

Comment: @Joris thanks for the support. I cast the first vote to close -almost there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, R is complaining because there's no opening {

```
foo <- function(string){   
 gsub(blah)
}
```

open curly, close curly.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I am embarrassed that I missed that.

Comment: although this was true for my test case, the error is still showing in the actual package, and I have changed the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

If `R CMD INSTALL` is still throwing an error, then it will generate a message along the line of `"check the file /path/to/00install.log" or similar` immediately at the end of the information printed to the console. Go and have a look at that log file as it will show exactly where the error occurred and a transcript of the preceding R calls leading to the error.

If `R CMD check` is throwing an error, there will be a similar note to look in the file `/path/to/check/directory/00check.log`, which again will contain useful information.

Does looking at those two files, whichever is appropriate, help? If not, post the content of the relevant log file and we might be able to give you more concrete advice.

At the moment, you assumption re the `\\#` does not appear to be a problem for R at all --- it parses that function just fine.

Comment: thanks for pointing me down the correct road to debugging. The only directory that `R CMD INSTALL` gives is: Error in `parse(outFile) : 
/tmp/RtmpQgt1SG/R.INSTALL63af5aad/PKG/R/foo.R:24:0: unexpected end of input` however, the directory `/tmp/Rtmp!gt1SG/` doesn't exist, and I can't find any log files in either the package directory or the directory where I run `R CMD INSTALL`... any other suggestions where I can look?

Comment: @David: If you are *still* getting that error (I've lost track of whether this was or was not related to the missing `{`?) then you have syntactically incorrect code in the file foo.R. Check it again, and then double check it. `R CMD INSTALL` is failing at the first hurdle. These things are frustrating but you do have to carefully step through code and check and double check you have it correct.

Comment: thanks for your help. In the process of debugging I got the error to disappear although I am not sure why; I have updated my answer with the details. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't re-create this issue via the steps below:

1. Copied `foo` into my global environment and ran `package.skeleton()`
2. Deleted lines 34-35 in `anRpackage/man/anRpackage-package.Rd`
3. Added a non-empty title to `anRpackage/man/foo.Rd`
4. Ran `R CMD build anRpackage/`
5. Ran `R CMD INSTALL anRpackage_1.0.tar.gz`
6. Ran `R CMD check anRpackage_1.0.tar.gz`

Everything worked, except `check`, which failed due to bad examples in `anRpackage-Ex.R`.  For reference, here's the `foo` I used.

```
foo <- function (filename, n) {
  text <- scan(file = filename, what = "character")
  if (n==1) text <- gsub("\\#GGG", '\\#', text)
  if (n>1)  text <- gsub("\\#GGG", '', text)
  writeLines(text, con = 'newfn.R')
}
```